# Dojo Tree Refresh

Tags: dojo, tree, refresh

Using Dojo 1.3, after adding a child (i.e. folder or item) to a tree, is there a way to have it reflected immediately via refresh or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

From the official [Dojo manual](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/Tree)

> Updating a Tree
>
> People often ask:
>
> how do I update a tree (adding or
> deleting items?)
>
> You can't update the
> tree directly, but rather you need to
> update the model. Usually the model is
> connected to a data store and in that
> case you need to update the data
> store. Thus, you need to use a data
> store that allows updates (through
> it's official API), like
> dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore.
>
> how do I refresh a Tree from the
> store?
>
> This isn't supported. The store
> needs to notify the tree of any
> changes to the data. Currently this is
> really only supported (out of the box)
> by dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore, as
> setting up a client-server dojo.data
> source where the server notifies the
> client whenever the data has changed
> is quite complicated, and beyond the
> scope of dojo, which is a client-only
> solution.

Answer (score 0):

Say, if your model has the query `{type:'continent'} - meaning any items with this property are top-level-items, then the following will model extension will monitor changes and refresh the tree's view

```
var dataStore = new ItemFileWriteStore( { ... });
new Tree({
  store: dataStore,
  model: new ForestModel({
    onNewItem: function(item, parentInfo){
        if(this.store.getValue(item, 'type') == 'continent'){
            this._requeryTop();
        }
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

This should in turn call `childrenChanged` in the tree and update it every time a new item is added.

See [model reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel.html)

As an addition, if the item added is not a toplevel item, an immediate update should be doable with this statement. `parent` is the treenode which has had an item added to its `children`.

```
tree._collapseNode(parent);
parent.state = 'UNCHECKED';
tree._expandNode(parent);
```

A more or less 'standard' refresh of the tree can be achieved by following. Reason for it not being added to base implementation, i think is because it will break the linkage with DnD features on a tree

```
dojo.declare("My.Tree", [dijit.Tree], {

           // Close the store? (So that the store will do a new fetch()).
         reloadStoreOnRefresh : true, 

         update: function() {
            this.model.store.clearOnClose = this.reloadStoreOnRefresh;
            this.model.store.close();

            // Completely delete every node from the dijit.Tree
            delete this._itemNodesMap;
            this._itemNodesMap = {};
            this.rootNode.state = "UNCHECKED";
            delete this.model.root.children;
            this.model.root.children = null;

            // Destroy the widget
            this.rootNode.destroyRecursive();

            // Recreate the model, (with the model again)
            this.model.constructor(this.model)

            // Rebuild the tree
            this.postMixInProperties();
            this._load();
         }
      }
);
```

Comment: badhorsie was using 1.3. it probably has to do with which type of store you use

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this WITHOUT needing the refresh.

```
_refreshNodeMapping: function (newNodeData) {

    if(!this._itemNodesMap[newNodeData.identity]) return;

    var nodeMapToRefresh = this._itemNodesMap[newNodeData.identity][0].item;
    var domNode = this._itemNodesMap[newNodeData.identity][0].domNode;

    //For every updated value, reset the old ones
    for(var val in newNodeData)
    {
        nodeMapToRefresh[val] = newNodeData[val];

        if(val == 'label')
        {
            domNode.innerHTML = newNodeData[val];
        }
    }  
}
```